# Polymorphism and reference class member - wrong virtual method called

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism

I was trying to understand how to apply polymorphism in C++ by creating a base class `Document` from which the two classes `Book` and `Newspaper` are derived. Note how the virtual method `get_content()` is overridden inside the derived classes.

```cpp
class Document {
public:
  virtual std::string get_content() const { return ""; }
};

class Book : public Document {
public:
  std::string get_content() const override { return "Book"; }
};

class Newspaper: public Document {
public:
  std::string get_content() const override { return "Newspaper"; }
};
```

The `Document` class is aggregated with the `Printer` class (by reference), and the `get_content()` method of the appropriate derived class is called according to the type of document.

```
class Printer {
public:
  const Document& m_doc;

  Printer(const Document& doc): m_doc(doc) {
    std::cout << "Printing... " << m_doc.get_content() << std::endl;
  }

  std::string get_content() const { return m_doc.get_content(); }
};
```

Until now everything works well, but once I aggregate the `Printer` class with another class `Binding`, the `get_content()` doesn't seem to call the method of the right derived class anymore.

```
class Binding {
public:
  Printer m_printer;

  Binding(const Printer& printer): m_printer(printer) {
    std::cout << "Binding... " << m_printer.get_content() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

I don't understand why the following piece of code...:

```cpp
int main() {
  Printer p1(Book{});
  Printer p2(Newspaper{});
  Binding b1(p1);
  Binding b2(p2);
}
```

...shows `Binding... Newspaper` at the third line while the `Printing` is clearly getting a `Book` instance as an input:

```
Printing... Book
Printing... Newspaper
Binding... Newspaper
Binding... Newspaper
```

Having `m_printer` declared as a reference inside `Binding` class doesn't fix this problem either.

Comment: In both cases `const Document& m_doc;` refers to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: `m_doc` is dangling in both `p1` and `p2` right after the constructor finishes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux another similar example to this one actually throws a segfault because `m_doc`. Should I use a pointer (unique_ptr) there instead as a class member?

Comment: @Hakim Whether you use a pointer or a reference, the same issue exists. You are creating `Printer` objects that refer to *temporary* `Document` objects that are destroyed while the `Printer` still refers to them. You have to make sure a `Document` object remains alive for at least as long as the `Printer` object that uses it. Yes, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` could be used to handle this lifetime management.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is there a way to address this problem without changing how the classes are connected?

Comment: @Hakim in the example shown, change `Printer p1(Book{}); Printer p2(Newspaper{});` to `Book b; Printer p1(b); Newspaper np; Printer p2(np);` Anything else would require you to change your class designs.

Comment: @Hakim Also, your `Document` object lacks a virtual destructor.  Thus anything like this: `Document *d = new Book;...delete d;` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Hakim -- C++ is a value-based language with deterministic destruction of objects.  It seems like you're trying to mimic reference-based languages such as Java.  If that's the case, don't use other programming languages as a model in writing C++ code.

Comment: You could perhaps replace your `Printer` with an `operator<<` overload? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/WaGzM4)

Comment: @Hakim You first have to ask yourself how the printer's lifetime should relate to the printable object's lifetime. Your reference solution can work, if the printed object outlives the printer. But this is no what you did by using temporary objects. If you want the printer to potentially outlive the printed object, it will have to share ownership of those objects (with `std::shared_ptr`) or make a copy of the object (probably with a `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: What was suggested by @RemyLebeau works as expected. On a side note, I wonder why though, knowing that the lifetime of the given argument is temporary, if I had this instead: `Book book; Newspaper newspaper; Binding p1(Printer{book}); Binding p2(Printer{newspaper});`, an additional method `Binding::get_content()` returns the right type of Document even if called after construction? if anyone could write a response below directly, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Hakim because `Binding` makes a *copy* of the `Printer` object it is given, thus also making a *copy* of its `Document&` reference (the temporary and the copy both reference the same `Document`). So `Binding` doesn't care whether or not the input `Printer` object is temporary, just so long as the `Document` object outlives the `Binding` object, otherwise you end up with the same dangling-reference issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Printer p1(Book{});
Printer p2(Newspaper{});
```

Here, you are using temporary objects. These objects are destroyed at the end of the statement they are created in.

So, you have dangling references.  Calling methods on a dangling reference is **undefined behaviour**.

In C++, you are in charge of object lifetime.

(Reference lifetime extension does not apply here)

Answer (score -2):

For my understanding, the example in question should work correctly providing output like

```
Printing... Book
Printing... Newspaper
Binding... Book
Binding... Newspaper
```

because of [lifetime extension of a temporary variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

Suspecting bugs in compiler is the last thing to do, but... Does used compiler correctly implement lifetime extension?

**UPD: lifetime extension rules are't applicable to `m_doc` class member, so my guess was wrong. There's is an undefined behaviour.**

Comment: No, the reference member `m_doc` is not bound to the temporary. Only the reference parameter `doc` of constructor `Printer::Printer(const Document& doc)` is bound to the temporary.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is priceless.